# GDB crashed in VSCode on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb, rcpp

I'm trying to debug Rcpp on Ubuntu 18.04. I followed the https://github.com/renkun-ken/vscode-rcpp-demo.

I installed R and VSCode and required packages all. When I run without debug, it works well. But If I add some breakpoints and start debugging, GDB crashed with 'No such file or directory' errors.

[image]

I don't know why this happens. How can I solve this?